# Is there any way I can fix a word header to a specific height?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge

I'm making a template for a letterhead, and I've put in mail merge fields for name/address. Some of my address records don't have some fields like name or address line 2. When these records are used, the fields end up blank and my greeting line and everything else moves up to compensate.

I was thinking that I could put these fields as part of my header, but the header shrinks in size just the same when displaying these records. So is there some way I can make it so that my greeting line and onward start no higher than a specific portion of my document?

Comment: This is an ugly hack, but insert a character and set the font to the background color of the letter (e.g., white) for "empty" fields. Word will faithfully reserve space on that line for the otherwise empty field. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this, depending on exactly how your document is set up.  Personally, I would add a single-cell table of fixed size and put the mail merge fields in there.  This will allow the spaces to slide up within the table and not impact the text outside the table (i.e., your main letter content).

Comment: Much better than my hack. I hate invisible tables personally (they lead to problems when you can't understand why you can't delete a space, for instance), but it should work for setting the spacing for the mail merge.

Comment: @allquixotic I usually have the outline of invisible tables shown, so that's not much of an issue for me at least. But the idea is good.